# Using Entity Framework Core 5, how can I automatically updated related entities when calling SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have two entities with a one to many relationship. `Samurais` and `Quotes`. One Samurai can have many Quotes.

I have a `DateModified` column on both the `Samurai` table and the `Quote` table.

I know how to use the `ChangeTracker` to iterate through all of the tracked entities and discover which ones have been Added or Modified. I am doing that in my `SaveChanges()` method below:

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    DateTime saveTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Update the createdDate and modifiedDate for all added entities
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added))
    {
        if (entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDate") != null && (DateTime)entry.Property("CreatedDate").CurrentValue == DateTime.MinValue)
            entry.Property("CreatedDate").CurrentValue = saveTime;

        if (entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("ModifiedDate") != null)
            entry.Property("ModifiedDate").CurrentValue = saveTime;
    }

    // Update the modifiedDate for all modified entities
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified))
    {
        if (entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("ModifiedDate") != null)
            entry.Property("ModifiedDate").CurrentValue = saveTime;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I add a `Quote` to a `Samurai` and call `SaveChanges()` only the `Quote` is Added. The related `Samurai` entity is unchanged. How can I get to the related `Samurai` entity and change the `EntityState` to modified so that my code above will update its `DateModified` column?

Comment: What will you then use this modified Samurai for?

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't really understand your question. I will use the modifiedDate to track delta changes.

Comment: But Samirai hasn't changed, Quote has.. unless you're making a business rule that a change to Wuote is a change to Samurai in which case my question is "why?" Or "what will you then do with this information?" For example if you want to show a list of the top ten most recently "changed because a wuote was changed" samurai you can just ask the db to get the max quote date per samurai and give you the top ten most recent max quote dates; you don't need to replicate it into samurai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. The Samurai entity has not been updated, which means that the ChangeTracker simply does not know anything about the Samurai at this moment.

The only solution I can think about for now is to somehow manage to access the Samurai before calling `SaveChanges`, and to mark it as modified. In this case, ChangeTracker will catch & update the Samurai's `ModifiedDate`.

```
// manually mark the samurai as an entity that has been modified
dbContext.Update(samurai); 
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Also, I think a good practice would be to introduce an Interface having the `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate` properties, and both Samurai and Quote to implement it, so you won't have to use reflection (which is expensive + too complicate) within SaveChanges logic.

```
// Update the modifiedDate for all modified entities
foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified && e.Entity is ITrackableDate))
{
    (entry as ITrackableDate).ModifiedDate.CurrentValue = saveTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, then in one to many relationship You are not modifying the 'one' side of relationship - you are creating a new entry on 'many' side linked by, lets say, ID - EF Core will correctly mark a new 'Quote' entry as created and 'Samurai' will be left untouched.

You could try to mark corresponding Samurai as 'modified' manually (also you could set modified date manually - force update on tracked entity - but I'm not sure if this works on shadow properties).

My way would be in this case in `SaveChanges` in `// Update the createdDate and modifiedDate for all added entities` loop to grab corresponding 'Samurai' id's and mark them as modified / update modified date.

Comment: I agree on the workflow. But how do I access the related Samurai entity?

Comment: In theory You could just create a dummy disconnected `Samurai` entity with only the `id` filled by data taken from corresponding `Quote`.
Then append this entity to change tracker and set it's state as 'unchanged'.
Next, modify the `modifiedDate` - it will mark only this property as changed - after calling save changes, it will be updated.